# Angular ui-grid: define columns in template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

The ui-grid documentation tells us to define columns in the controller, like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'id', displayName: 'Ref', width: "60" },
        { field: 'title', displayName: 'Title', width: "200" }
    ]
}
```

While this works fine, I feel that this really belongs in my template. Is there some way to setup the columns like this:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="myGrid" style="width:800px; height: 600px">
    <ui-column field="id" width="60">Ref</ui-column>
    <ui-column field="title" width="200">Title</ui-column>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think (happy to be proved wrong!) you can do this. Instead, I tend to keep my `columnDefs` in a separate `JSON` file which I load through my `dataFactory`. This way, your grid template/view definition is kept separate from your angular logic